# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'use_cache'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Running Django tests

./manage.py test

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 346, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 74, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 90, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_coverage/coverage_runner.py", line 71, in run_tests
    coverage.use_cache(settings.COVERAGE_USE_CACHE)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'use_cache'
```

I've tried many things but I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: reinstall python again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The django-coverage module doesn't seem to have been updated in a while. It relies on an older version of [coverage.py](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy).

You can try to install an older version of coverage.py, or drop django-coverage.